# Unable to get dropdown value in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, learning new things in react and have created a dropdown for a country and want store the value in app.js. I couldn't able to get the value from the dropdown field. Can anyone help me to get the value?

Here is the some code:

```
<Select
          placeholder="Select your country"
          options={countryOptions}
          value={this.props.country}
          onChange={this.props.handleCountry}
        />
```

Here is the whole code:

"https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-bell-elme4".

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `handleCountry` should accept two params:

```
  handleCountry = (e, obj) => {
    this.setState({
      country: obj.value
    });
  };
```

See this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hill-lh3tf?file=/src/App.js:278-365) for a working example.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, I coudn't able to open sandbox to see the working one. Could you please update it again?

Comment: The link is working for me.  Not sure what to update.  https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hill-lh3tf?file=/src/App.js:278-365

Comment: Note, I also updated the submit button:  `<Button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</Button>`